# Python socket.io ack function

Tags: javascript, python, web, socket.io, ack

In JS socket.io, there's the third param in the emit function of client:

```
client.emit("event name",{some:"data"},function myack(value){
})
```

The `myack` function is passed to server and called with some returning value:

```
//server side:
myack("foobar");
...
```

However, I don't see this feature in Python socket.io: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncserver-class

Can `ack` function be passed to Python socket.io server from clientside JS socket.io? Supposed to be using the same application protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, have a look at the docs:
https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#event-callbacks

From these docs:

> When a client sends an event to the server, it can optionally provide
> a callback function, to be invoked as a way of ***acknowledgment*** that the
> server has processed the event. While this is entirely managed by the
> client, the server can provide a list of values that are to be passed
> on to the callback function, simply by returning them from the handler
> function:
>
> ```
> @sio.event def my_event(sid, data):
>     # handle the message
>     return "OK", 123
> ```
>
> Likewise, the server can request a callback function to be invoked after a client has processed an event. The
> **socketio.Server.emit() method has an optional callback argument that
> can be set to a callable**. If this argument is given, the callable will
> be invoked after the client has processed the event, and any values
> returned by the client will be passed as arguments to this function.
> Using callback functions when broadcasting to multiple clients is not
> recommended, as the callback function will be invoked once for each
> client that received the message.

So:

```py
# main.py
import random
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret!"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


# Create a route for the index page (http://localhost:5000/)
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return send_from_directory(".", "index.html")

# Start listening for connecting clients
@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    print("Client connected")

# Create a function to act as an ack function
def ack_random_number_received(data):
    print("The client received the random number!", data)

# Start listening for "some_event" events
@socketio.on("some_event")
def handle_some_event():

    # Create a random number (just for demo purposes)
    random_number = random.randint(0, 10)

    # Registering a "callback" function here will act as an ack function
    emit("random_number_picked", random_number, callback=ack_random_number_received)

    # Returning here will send data (a string in this case) to the ack function in JS
    return "Ack from Python"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The random number is: <span id="random-number">...</span></p>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Connect to the server
            var socket = io();

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.group('Event: connect');
                console.log('Emit "some_event"');
                socket.emit('some_event', {somedata: 123}, function(ack) {
                    console.group('Ack function triggered for "some_event"');
                    console.log('The server acknowledged our event, this is the response:', ack);
                    console.groupEnd();
                });
                console.groupEnd();
            });

            // Listen for events
            socket.on('random_number_picked', function(newNumber, callback) {

                // Add some logging
                console.group('Event: random_number_picked');
                console.log('The new random number is', newNumber);
                console.log('The ack function is', callback);

                // Update a part of the page
                document.getElementById("random-number").innerHTML = newNumber;

                // Invoke the callback function to send an ack to Python
                callback("Ack from JS");
                console.groupEnd();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Browser console log]

[image: Python console log]

Comment: i dont see any description of ack function in that doc; only event handlers

Comment: @datdinhquoc, it's really there.. Anyway, I've updated my answer with a full working example. Hope that helps

Comment: This is a great example.  That 2nd arg, 'callback', on the js side event handler function was very unclear to me that it was a predefined function your handler was going to be passed by the system.  This cleared it up and now I have it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify the answer by Gijs Wobben:

Client side:

```js
sio.emit("eventname",data,function ackfunc(ackval){
     console.log(ackval);
});
```

Server side:

```py
def eventname_func(sid,data):
    ...
    return ackval # This be thrown to ackfunc at client

sio.on("eventname",eventname_func)
```